# TFS 2010: Setting a work item field readonly for all users excepting administrators doesn't work

Tags: tfs

I'm customizing some TFS2010 process template and I need to restrict some fields so everyone excepting administrators will be having them "read-only".

Problem is I'm using "readonly" rule and this is setting "read-only" for all, even if "not for [Global]\Project Collection Administrators" is specified.

My domain user is within [Global]\Project Collection Administrators, I added myself from Administration Console or from VS2010 GUI, and no luck.

I'm using TFS2010 Power Tools, but this is the generated XML:

```
<FieldDefinition reportable="dimension" refname="System.Title" name="Title" type="String">
  <READONLY for="[Global]\Project Collection Valid Users" not="[Global]\Project Collection Administrators" />
</FieldDefinition>
```

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Actually, after saving WIT, if I open it from server using Power Tools, I found that I've two "READONLY" rules, one with "for valid users" and "not blank", and second with "for blank" and "not project collection administrators"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try clearing the rule that sets the Readonly value for valid users.  Since collection admins are also valid users then both rules are applicable.  By just having the second one, all users will pick up the readonly rule by default, unless they are project connection admins.

Comment: Hey. I'm just trying that... Anyway, it should be strange, since any global or local group is "valid users", so, how this filters works?...

Comment: Thanks, I had no success with that. Maybe I'm/we are misunderstanding how "readonly" rule works. I've tried that with project-scope groups, like Readers, Contributors, and Builders, and same result...

Comment: In the end, you're absolutely right. BTW, mainly, permissions were applied but those weren't effective without a Team Explorer/VS2010 reboot. It's that easy........